# Tkinter store filename through menubar button

Tags: python, tkinter, menubar, filedialog

I have created functions that can display graphs and tables of csv files in a GUI I am making with tkinter.

I have a `menubar` with an *import* button, a *plot* button, and a *table* button. The *plot* and *table* button can successfully plot graphs and tables of csv  files respectively.

What I'd like to do, is when the user selects the *import* button, they select a file of their choice. Then, if they happen to select the *plot* button, the plot function works on the file they chose from *import*. Moreover, if they happen to select the *table* button, the table function works on the file they chose from *import*.

I have created a file opening function called `openfile()` which remembers the name of the file opened.

The problem is that I don't know how to use `menubar` and `openfile()` such when the *import* button is clicked, my application stores  the filename.

Any tips on how I would go about doing this?

Here's the code I've written for the `menubar` and `openfile()`:

```
def openfile():
    name= askopenfilename() 
    return (name[19:])

class MyApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "MyApp")
        # main frame
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # creates the menubar at the top of the window
        menubar = tk.Menu(container)

        # import menu for importing csv files, initializes a file opening function (tbd)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Import a CSV File", command = file_openerfunction)
        menubar.add_cascade(label= "Import", menu=filemenu)

        # plot menu for creating graphs and figures
        Plot = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff =0 )
        Plot.add_command(label="Plot My CSV File", command= popupgraph)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Plot", menu=Plot)

        # table menu for viewing data in a table
        table = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
        table.add_command(label="View MY CSV File", command = table)
        table.add_cascade(label = "View Data", menu = table)

        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=table)
        ....
        ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest you take an **Object Oriented** approach to split each component behaviour.

This way, you would have a class App, where you would initialise the main components of the app:

```
class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        ...

        ...
        # Menubar
        self.menubar = MyMenuBar(self)

        # Filemenu
        self.filemenu = MyFileMenu(self, menubar)

        # Plot
        self.plot = MyPlot(self, menubar)

        # The rest for all the other components
        ...

    def get_import_filename(self):
        # Ask the child for the filename and return it
        return self.filemenu.get_filename()
```

And then define every of your objects:

```
class MyPlot(tk.Menu):
      def __init__(self, parent, menubar):
           tk.Menu.__init__(self, menubar, tearoff=0)
           self.parent = parent
           self.initialize()

      def initialize(self):
          self.add_command(label="Plot My CSV File", command= self.popupgraph)  

      def popupgraph(self):
          # Ask the parent for the filename
          filename = self.parent.get_import_filename()
          # Do whatever with the filename...like open a file

class MyFileMenu(tk.Menu):
      def __init__(self, parent, menubar):
           tk.Menu.__init__(self, menubar, tearoff=0)
           self.parent = parent
           self.initialize()
      def initialize(self):
          self.add_command(label="Import a CSV File", command = file_opener)
      def file_opener(self):
          # Your file opener function goes here
          ...
          # At the end, save the imported file:
          self.filename = filename
      def get_filename(self):
          return self.filename
```

Finally, have the main to run it:

```
def main():
    app = App(None)
    app.title('Auto login')
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne! this works great. I'm going to take your advice and change my code into a more object oriented approach. With regards to the file opening problem, I found a very simple way for the GUI to remember the file selected: have the file selected be stored in a list, then call popupgraph on the list element.

Comment: why does your example have two classes named `MyPlot`?

Comment: @BryanOakley typo mistake. Sorry. Editing now.

Answer (score 0):

otorrillas solution worked perfectly.

I found another simple way to resolve this issue. In order for the GUI to remember the file selected from *import*, have the file name be appended to a list. Then, call on `popupgraph()` and `viewcsv()` on the list element. Here's the new code for my file opening function.

```
file_list = []

def openfile():
    name= askopenfilename() 
    file_list.append(name[19:])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the way you were trying to do some things (or *why* you were doing them at all in some cases), but here's a runnable example that creates a simple `Choices` cascading menu in the upper-left corner of the window of simple tkinter app. Hopefully you';; be able to adapt and integrate it into your project's code.

I made The command for importing CSV files, `file_openerfunction`, a class method and have it call the `openfile()` function because that way the returned value (the filename) can be store as an attribute in `self.filename`. This will allow it to used in the other command choices after it is create (so they will know what file to operate upon).

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
    from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
except ModuleNotFoundError:   $ Python 3
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

def openfile():
    name = askopenfilename()
    return name[19:]

class MyApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.title("MyApp")

        self.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        top = self.winfo_toplevel()
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(top)
        top['menu'] = self.menubar

        self.submenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label='Choices', menu=self.submenu)

        self.submenu.add_command(label="Import a CSV File",
                                 command=self.file_openerfunction)
        self.submenu.add_command(label="Plot My CSV File",
                                 command=self.popupgraph)
        self.submenu.add_command(label="View MY CSV File",
                                 command=self.table)

    def file_openerfunction(self):
        self.filename = openfile()

    def popupgraph(self): pass
    def table(self): pass

app = MyApp()
app.mainloop()
```

I also suggest you read and follow the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which will help standardize the code your write and improve its readability.